# 讨 at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: meaning, usage

An example from a dictionary:

"讨不讨厌呀！Isn't that annoying?"

The first 讨 usage isn't clear here, as for beginner. Is it a special grammar structure? Maybe even an accidental mistake in the dictionary? (in case it happens sometimes)

Partly reminds tag question, but then it probably should have been "讨厌不讨厌" not "讨不讨厌", I'm not sure how it is used with multi-character words.

Comment: "去不去？" equals to "去还是不去？", "去 or 不去？", "去吗？", similarly, "喜欢不喜欢？" equals to "喜欢吗？", or can be shorten to "喜不喜欢？".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "討厭不討厭？" is a substantially shortened version of "討厭？還是不討厭？"

As you can see, it is quite wordy. In practicality, "討厭不討厭？"  is still one character too long. The standard practice is to shorten it down to "討(厭)不討厭?" (the shorter the better)

Similarly:

- "明白不明白？" is  always shortened to 明不明白？or even further to "明不明？"
- "知道不知道？" is  always shortened to 知不知道？or even further to "知不知？"

Avoid wordiness and omit as much as possible as long as the meaning is clear is consider good writing.

Comment: Also common: 可不可以

Answer (score 1):

people use shorten version mostly. full version is used very rare, but it does make sense too. it's kinda structurelised. besides the examples above, there are more: 烦人--烦不烦人？， 要脸-- 要不要脸？，上来-- 上不上来？..... it seems that these are always questioning (though the speaker may not expect the answer back.)